# Screen tearing when moving up and down quickly

Tags: civilization-5, technical-issues

I bought this game a few weeks ago and noticed I'm getting screen tearing in the middle of the screen.  I've tried using in game v-sync and adaptive v-sync and neither seems to solve the problem.  I don't see to have this issue with any other game.  Also my fps stay under the the refresh rate of my monitor

Anyone know how to solve this problem?  I'm using Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 if that helps!

Comment: What is monitor refresh rate? I know *some* games may have issues if you run 120-144 Hz. For example did I get tearing in skyrim at 144 Hz, but 120 Hz works without a hitch. *If* your monitor is 144 Hz, I'd try different refresh rate settings.

Answer (score 2):

Typically 'screen tearing' is caused by a game updating the video/graphics buffer that is rendered on the screen before the previous buffer was rendered on the screen. A basic lesson, the graphics for your screen are stored in memory and then rendered on the screen. Sometimes games will change the buffered image before the previous cycle completed. If the game pushes a frame to the buffer before the monitors refresh rate hits you will get tearing.

There are two solutions to this problem, the first comes from the fact that the update to the buffer should (typically) occur when the monitor is restarting it's rendering cycle (known as V-SYNC). If you have the option in your settings try turning on V-SYNC. If V-SYNC is on when having issues you might try turning it off instead. Generally you always want V-SYNC on unless you want tearing or unexpected graphical artifacts.

The other option is based on a typical solution that most games use to prevent the problem. They use multiple buffers (2 or 3 typically) so while one buffer is being rendered, the other is being updated. Some games have an option to enable double or triple buffering, if so, enable it.

Souce: [Game Programming Algorithms and Techniques: A Platform-Agnostic Approach](http://smile.amazon.com/Game-Programming-Algorithms-Techniques-Platform-Agnostic/dp/0321940156/)

Comment: I wasn't able to post more links: Here's some info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing

Answer (score -1):

So you're going to need to tweak your GPU. Download [GeForce Experience](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience), Nvidia's native software. Open it up, and change the `Output FPS` to `59`. This is because the magic number here is 60. When the FPS goes above that, you start getting issues. So switch off V-Sync, and Adaptive V-Sync, follow the instructions above, and say goodbye to tearing or input lag.

Comment: It's not going above 60.  It's staying at 59.9(Using Evga Precision to view fps).